# Access problems using the Factory Pattern on C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I am very newbie with patterns, and I am starting to study the Factory Pattern to do an exercise about Geometric Figures.

This is my code for this case:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class MainApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Problem: I can't access to 
            //the Cube() builder because it's private.
            GeometricFigure cube = new Cube(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Blablabla");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

This is my "Creator" method that implements the Factory pattern

```
public abstract class GeometricFigure
{
    private float Dimension { get; set; }
    private float Coordinate_X { get; set; }
    private float Coordinate_Y { get; set; }
    private float Coordinate_Z { get; set; }

    public GeometricFigure()
    {
        CreateFigure();
    }

    //Factory method
    public abstract void CreateFigure();
}
```

And this is my "ConcrateCreator" class

```
class Cube : GeometricFigure
{
    public override void CreateFigure() 
    {
        new Cube(); 
    }
}
```

I think that my code is good.... but... I can't understand why the Cube class is private. To sum up, Is it correct set to public the Cube Class? and if the answwer is not... How can I instance the cube object from the Main method if the Cube class it's private? :(

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Emma.

Comment: Your Cube class is actually `internal` by default when you don't specify an access modifier on it. If you want it to be accessible outside its assembly then you'd have to set it public.

Comment: What do you expect the line `new Cube();` to do?

Comment: Here you get a good example of how the to properly implement a Factory-Pattern:

https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Comment: I think you should study on OOP before design patterns. Whole design pattern approach is based on OOP. And you can check the access modifiers also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming

Comment: Your pattern should return an instance you've created. It shouldn't be void

Comment: Thanks @ADyson but... setting public the Cube class... it can be a kind of anti pattern?

Comment: @EmmaDev in what sense? If you want to use it outside its immediate environment, you need to make it accessible. Why do you think this violates the pattern? BTW as others have mentioned I'm not sure you've implemented a classical factory pattern here anyway. Take a look at those links.

Answer (score 3):

As people mentioned, default access modifier for the class in C# is `Internal`, which makes your classes accessible only in the same assembly they declared. Also, you mix the object you want to create with the actual factory. The factory is a separate instance which creates an object. Let's say you have this abstraction:

```
public abstract class GeometricFigure
{
    public float Dimension { get; set; }
    public float Coordinate_X { get; set; }
    public float Coordinate_Y { get; set; }
    public float Coordinate_Z { get; set; }
}
```

And derived class:

```
    public class Triangle: GeometricFigure
    {
        public float Dimension { get; set; }
        public float Coordinate_X { get; set; }
        public float Coordinate_Y { get; set; }
        public float Coordinate_Z { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you want to create a factory which should create an instance:

```
public abstract class GeometricFigureFactory
{
   public abstract GeometricFigure Create();
}
```

And the concrete implementation of this factory:

```
    public class TriangleFactory: GeometricFigureFactory
    {
        public override GeometricFigure Create()
        {
            return new Triangle();
        }
    }
```

And the usage:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var factory = new TriangleFactory();

            var triangle = factory.Create();
        }
    }
```

The advantages of this pattern are the Open Close Principle which you will not violate each time you need to add a new instance which inherits from `GeometricFigure`. You simply create a new factory which extends `GeometricFigureFactory`. Also, you can polymorphically use both factories and `GeometricFigure` entities

P.S. Updated your private getters and setters to the public, since they already encapsulate private fields

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I just want to add that this is the Abstract Factory pattern, as opposed to the Factory Method pattern, which is way simpler and in many cases the way to go. Especially true if your trying to understand the factory pattern overall. In that case the Factory Class would look something like this: `public static class GeometricShapeFactory { public static Triangle CreateTriangle() { return new Triangle(); } }` and Main would be `public static void Main() { var triangle = GeometricShapeFactory.CreateTriangle(); }`

Comment: @crazy_crank I personally don't like `static` since it's not possible to fake behavior for unit tests. You can always register the factory as a singleton if you need it

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible solutions.

1. Make Cube public.
2. Create it in the same namespace using a factory method on another, public class.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are calling the abstract class directly. Perhaps doing

```
Cube cube = new Cube();
```

instead of

```
GeometricFigure cube = new Cube();
```

would make a difference.

The following links also provide a lot of useful information on the factory pattern:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFVTgRHJLM

Hope any of this helps, and if not, would love to try to help you further!